# ros_arduino_bridge configuration error

Tags: ros, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i follow read me tutorial of ros_arduino_bridge in this link [link text](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge) and when i run `roslaunch ros_arduino_python arduino.launch`, i receive this error:

> Connecting to Arduino on port
> /dev/ttyACM0 ... Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/home/irisecesi/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/nodes/arduino_node.py",
> line 195, in 
> myArduino = ArduinoROS()   File "/home/irisecesi/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/nodes/arduino_node.py",
> line 87, in **init**
> self.controller.connect()   File "/home/irisecesi/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/src/ros_arduino_python/arduino_driver.py",
> line 68, in connect
> test = self.get_baud()   File "/home/irisecesi/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/src/ros_arduino_python/arduino_driver.py",
> line 261, in get_baud
> return int(self.execute('b'));   File
> "/home/irisecesi/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/src/ros_arduino_python/arduino_driver.py",
> line 178, in execute
> return int(value) TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number,
> not 'NoneType' [INFO] [WallTime:
> 1468423834.069478] Stopping the robot... [INFO] [WallTime:
> 1468423834.070452] Shutting down Arduino Node... [arduino-1] process
> has died [pid 10979, exit code 1, cmd
> /home/irisecesi/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/nodes/arduino_node.py
> __name:=arduino __log:=/home/irisecesi/.ros/log/3ed0dd4c-4904-11e6-9d6d-eca86bf97b81/arduino-1.log].
> log file:
> /home/irisecesi/.ros/log/3ed0dd4c-4904-11e6-9d6d-eca86bf97b81/arduino-1*.log all processes on machine have died,
> roslaunch will exit shutting down
> processing monitor... ... shutting
> down processing monitor complete done

What can i do please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239441/ros_arduino_bridge-configuration-error/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-07-13**:
Can you please provide the following additional information: (1) Your version of Ubuntu, (2) Your version of ROS, (3) Which branch of ros_arduino_bridge are you using (e.g. hydro-devel, indigo-devel), (4) which Arduino board are you using (e.g. Uno, Mega, etc.)

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-07-14**:
I use ubuntu 14.04 , ros indigo, arduino mega and ros_arduino_bridge indigo-devel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the additional info.  I have added a try-except around the get_baud() function that should fix this.  Please do a "git pull" and see if it works for you.  It might also help to increase the timeout parameter in your params file from the default of 0.1 to 0.5.  There should be no need to rerun catkin_make.

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0